# Items are not appearing in Listview

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, listview, directory

I apologize if I'm missing something simple, I'm still learning. This is my first attempt at recursion. this program is supposed to do the following, First I open my FileBrowserDialog, then the listview Populates with the file names within the folder selected. However, when I select the folder it fills the listview but I cannot see any names and my listview freezes. the reason I know it fills is the scroll bar adjusts. this is my code:

```
#region FileHandlers



    void FolderSearch(string sFol)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sFol))
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                {

                    listView1.Items.Add(f);
                }
                FolderSearch(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }
    }

    public void ChooseFolder()
    {
        string pPath;

        if(folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

            FolderSearch(pPath);
        }
    }

    #endregion
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChooseFolder();
    }
```

Comment: The reason behind the freezing could be the very big hierarchy of the selected folder. Try loading the file names of only selected folder and see if you face the same issue. Comment the line `FolderSearch(d);` and see it fills the listview with file names of the selected folder only.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this as well as using a test folder with only a couple folders within. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: You code tries to load the sub directories of the selected folder and their files before loading files of the selected folder. So if the sub directories don't have any files in them there won't be any items added to listview even if the selected folder does have files in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code skips the selected folder and it  will only get  files from subfolders within selected folder, because you are first calling `GetDirectories` method, if you don't have subfolders within selected folder or your subfolders dont have files, it will get nothing.

Try this

```
 void FolderSearch(string sFol)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sFol))
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(f);
            }

            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sFol))
            {                  
                FolderSearch(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

and also if you want only file name use `GetFileName` method from `System.IO.Path` class. `listView1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));`

Comment: I actually managed to fix it before this answer, however I did it in a similar way you mentioned. Thank you for the help though.  That last bit you said was actually going to be my next task, so thank you!